# Failing to boot Windows 10 after trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I was trying to install Ubuntu from live usb but I made some mistake and now I can't start my Windows 10

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda1 has
                       204799 sectors, but according to the info from fdisk,
                       it has 997375 sectors.
    Operating System: 
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 16392 of /dev/sdc1 for its
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed.
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System: 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

ubuntu-vg-root': _______________________________________________________________

    File system:      
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

ubuntu-vg-swap_1': _____________________________________________________________

    File system:      
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       999,423       997,376  83 Linux
/dev/sda2           1,001,470 1,953,523,711 1,952,522,242   5 Extended
/dev/sda5           1,001,472 1,953,523,711 1,952,522,240  8e Linux LVM


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdc: 3,8 GiB, 4105175040 bytes, 8017920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *          2,048     8,017,919     8,015,872   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs  
/dev/sda1        B02A2F5B2A2F1DBA                       ntfs      
/dev/sda5        fs2K0v-KVeE-vfxU-lj3f-Szl7-SQG8-leoIQb LVM2_member
/dev/sdc1        0E28-9F59                              vfat       UBUNTU 16_0

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
ubuntu--vg-root
ubuntu--vg-swap_1

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdc1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd    /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd    /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd    /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd    /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdc1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000  15 12 85 9d 01 12 82 09  0f 00 03 15 12 85 99 01  |................|
00000010  12 82 05 0e 0e 12 85 d9  0d 00 01 15 12 85 99 01  |................|
00000020  12 82 3d 12 81 4d 10 00  02 15 12 85 99 01 12 82  |..=..M..........|
00000030  3d 12 81 4d 12 82 09 0e  00 02 15 12 85 99 01 12  |=..M............|
00000040  82 09 12 82 05 0e 0b 00  01 15 12 85 99 01 12 82  |................|
00000050  05 0e 0c 00 02 15 12 85  99 01 12 82 05 0e 0e 05  |................|
00000060  20 02 01 09 0e 08 20 03  01 12 82 05 0e 0e 0b 20  | ..... ........ |
00000070  04 01 12 82 05 0e 0e 11  81 35 06 20 01 01 12 82  |.........5. ....|
00000080  05 07 20 02 01 12 82 05  0e 04 06 11 81 35 04 06  |.. ..........5..|
00000090  11 82 25 07 20 02 01 0e  12 82 09 0a 20 03 01 0e  |..%. ....... ...|
000000a0  12 82 09 12 82 31 13 20  03 15 12 85 99 01 12 82  |.....1. ........|
000000b0  55 11 82 4d 12 85 e1 12  85 e1 10 20 02 15 12 85  |U..M....... ....|
000000c0  99 01 12 82 55 11 82 4d  12 85 e1 05 20 00 12 85  |....U..M.... ...|
000000d0  e1 06 20 01 01 12 85 e1  09 20 02 01 12 85 e1 12  |.. ...... ......|
000000e0  85 e1 0f 20 04 01 12 85  e1 12 85 e1 12 85 e5 11  |... ............|
000000f0  82 4d 0d 20 01 15 12 85  99 01 12 82 55 12 85 e1  |.M. ........U...|
00000100  10 20 02 15 12 85 99 01  12 82 55 12 85 e1 11 82  |. ........U.....|
00000110  4d 05 20 00 11 82 49 05  28 00 11 82 49 05 20 00  |M. ...I.(...I. .|
00000120  11 81 89 05 28 00 12 85  e1 05 28 00 11 81 89 0b  |....(.....(.....|
00000130  20 02 12 81 95 11 81 89  12 85 e1 0c 20 03 12 81  | ........... ...|
00000140  95 11 81 89 12 85 e1 0e  10 20 03 12 85 b1 12 82  |......... ......|
00000150  09 0e 15 12 85 e9 02 0e  0e 13 20 03 15 12 85 99  |.......... .....|
00000160  01 12 82 09 0e 0e 15 12  85 e9 02 0e 0e 08 20 01  |.............. .|
00000170  12 85 b1 12 82 09 0f 20  00 15 12 85 99 01 15 12  |....... ........|
00000180  85 a1 01 12 82 09 10 20  02 12 85 b1 12 85 e1 15  |....... ........|
00000190  12 85 a1 01 12 85 ed 0b  20 02 12 85 b1 12 82 09  |........ .......|
000001a0  12 81 95 0b 20 02 12 85  b1 12 82 09 12 85 e1 12  |.... ...........|
000001b0  20 01 15 12 85 99 01 15  12 85 a1 01 12 81 00 56  | ..............V|
000001c0  19 3e 8e fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 20 61 74 00 00  |.>......... at..|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on ubuntu-vg-root'


Unknown BootLoader on ubuntu-vg-swap_1'



========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdb

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-WQaoX9BA/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-WQaoX9BA/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
  skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name ubuntu-vg-root'.
  Volume group name "ubuntu-vg-root'" has invalid characters.
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg-root'
  skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name ubuntu-vg-root'.
  Volume group name "ubuntu-vg-root'" has invalid characters.
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg-root'
  skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name ubuntu-vg-root'.
  Volume group name "ubuntu-vg-root'" has invalid characters.
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg-root'
hexdump: /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root': No such file or directory
  skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name ubuntu-vg-swap_1'.
  Volume group name "ubuntu-vg-swap_1'" has invalid characters.
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg-swap_1'
  skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name ubuntu-vg-swap_1'.
  Volume group name "ubuntu-vg-swap_1'" has invalid characters.
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg-swap_1'
  skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name ubuntu-vg-swap_1'.
  Volume group name "ubuntu-vg-swap_1'" has invalid characters.
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg-swap_1'
hexdump: /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-swap_1': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-swap_1': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Disable secure boot in BIOS and check if You can boot.

Comment: DONE. But after reboot I get: default boot device missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: OK, so what now? I can't install ubuntu, I can't repair win 10 (repiar usb disc). Should I install win 10 one again?

Comment: This question is definitely ***NOT*** a duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) That's a generic how-to-install question, whereas this one presents a specific problem, including Boot Info Script output that reveals a specific reason for that problem. There may be another question that's a close duplicate of this one, but it's isn't the one suggested by others.

Comment: **Voted to leave open** See answer...

Answer (score 3):

You've accidentally wiped your Windows installation. Your only certain option to get it booting again is to re-install it, either from installation media or from a backup. There's a *slim* chance that [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) could recover enough of the original installation to boot, or at least to recover files relatively easily.

If you have no backup and your disk contained important personal files, ***STOP USING IT NOW!!!*** As the disk contained Windows, you may do better to ask about data recovery on a Windows forum, but you'll probably need to use a tool like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to locate and copy files from the original disk to *another physical disk.* (If you don't have such a disk, you'll need to obtain one.) If you're ***very*** lucky, you might be able to recover entire partitions by deleting the ones that exist and then using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the old partitions; however, the probability of at least a few files being damaged is pretty high.

As a side note, if the computer came with Windows 10 pre-installed, it almost certainly booted in EFI mode using a GUID Partition Table (GPT); but your Boot Info Script output indicates that your disk currently uses the Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table, which is more commonly used with BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting. This may be a clue to what went wrong. My suspicion is that you either followed (bad) advice to enable the CSM in your firmware prior to installing Ubuntu, or that option was enabled for some other reason. You then unknowingly booted the Ubuntu installer in BIOS mode, saw a complaint about the EFI-mode install of Windows on GPT, and made the mistake of converting the disk from GPT to MBR form, in the process wiping out Windows, in order to work around that error message. The correct approach, however, was to boot the installer in EFI mode. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject. That page won't help you recover your data, but it may help you avoid making the same mistake again.